# Remove from Array doesn't update reference inside variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Normally altering a reference to an object/array, alters the object and vice versa.

```
var someArr = [{letter: 'a'}, {letter: 'b'}, {letter: 'c'}];
var test = someArr[1];

test.letter = 'k';
// or
// someArr[1].letter = 'k'

console.log(test.letter); // outputs k
console.log(someArr[1].letter); // outputs k
```

A reference to an array index' value (which is an object) won't change if the value of said index changes - e.g. if the value is removed via `splice`, the reference won't point to the new value that took it's place at that index. It still holds the reference to the removed value. Why?

```
var someArr = [{letter: 'a'}, {letter: 'b'}, {letter: 'c'}];
var test = someArr[1];

someArr.splice(1, 1); // remove object with letter b

console.log(test.letter); // outputs b <-- Why not c?
console.log(someArr[1].letter); // outputs c
```

Here is a JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rf47jyxv/

I don't want to know **that** it is like that. I know it is like that.
I would like to know **why** it is like that.

Why, after `splice`, is the variable `test` that holds a reference to `someArr[1]` different than calling `someArr[1]` directly?

Comment: at the second example: you've passed second element to a varibale and then you remove this second element from the array. so it's ok why test.letter gives b not c.

Comment: Well, I thought c is now the second element. Because it is from now on accessible with `someArr[1]`

Comment: with help of splice you remove the second so c becomes second element. the array is then truly altered.

Comment: yes and the reference to the second element does not reflect that. That's my problem. I know now that it is just is like that but it doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: at the first example: in my console it prints k not h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `test` is holding a reference to object `{letter: 'b'}` which at some point was the second item in `someArray`.

Answer (score 2):

The objects in `someArr` are different, and have their own reference. You have assigned the reference of second object to `test`

So, now `test` has the reference of second object and removing the second objec from the array does not delete the reference, as you might think, because `test` still has the reference of second object intact.

After splicing, the third object takes place of second object, so `someArr[1]` is `{letter: 'c'}`, so it logs `c`

```
var someArr = [{letter: 'a'}, {letter: 'b'}, {letter: 'c'}];

// diff refs ------^--------------^---------------^ say r1, r2, r3 and r1 != r2 != r3

var test = someArr[1]; // r2

someArr.splice(1, 1); // you removed r2 in array but it is still being referred by test

console.log(test.letter); // outputs b as test, still has the r2 reference
console.log(someArr[1].letter); // outputs c, as it has r3 reference.
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But it doesn't really answer *why* this is happening. You say yourself, after splicing the third object is available under the second reference `someArr[1]` - which is exactly what the variable `test` is holding. Yet, it outputs something else.

Comment: "someArr[1] - which is exactly what the variable `test` is holding" - no, variable `test` is holding a reference to object `{letter: 'b'}` which at some point was the second item in `someArray`

Comment: @Igor thanks that made it clear to me. `test` holds a reference to the object, not the index of the array. I'd accept that sentence as an answer if you care to write one.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you accepted an answer (both the others are good), but I wanted to give an additional description of what is going on.

Arrays in JavaScript are not Arrays like they appear. JavaScript Arrays are basically a glorified Javascript Object. Array's in JavaScript reference/point to other objects, it is more of a Map with sequential/increasing key values instead of an Array with indexes.

So under the hood, the second element of your array `someArr` is pointing to an object `{letter:b}` somewhere else in ram. When you create your value `test`, it also points to that specific object. Changes to that object are reflected both by the Array `someArr` and by the var `test`.

When you remove the reference at index 2 via your `splice(1,1)`, it no longer was pointed to by your Array `someArr`. However, it is still pointed to by `test`. (So at that, it is not going to get garbage collected until test points to something else).

`test` is not referencing the address in an array, `test` is referencing an object/address that `someArr` was pointing to when you created `test`.

The following reading might help more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/understanding-javascript-arrays/

Comment: I didn't edit to say something different. I edited to add that `test` does not hold a reference to `someArr[1]`, which is what I stated in my question.
Anyways I appreciate your explanation - it helped too! +1

Comment: My apologies, will remove that statement from my response! Glad to hear the additional explanation helped :)